# Syntax error when using check unit testing framework with C99

Tags: c, testing, c99, autotools, check-framework

I'm running into a weird syntax error when I try to compile tests using the [check unit testing framework](http://check.sourceforge.net/) with the `-std=c99` flag.

So, I'm trying to compile the `example.c`:

```
#include <check.h>
START_TEST(example) {
  fail();
} END_TEST
int main(int argc, char** argv){ return 0; }
```

using autotools, with `Makefile.am`:

```
check_PROGRAMS = example
example_SOURCES = example.c
example_CFLAGS = @CHECK_CFLAGS@ -Wall -pedantic -std=c99
example_LDADD = @CHECK_LIBS@
```

and `configure.ac`:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.61])
AC_INIT([example], [1.0.0], [noreply@here.com])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([foreign -Wall -Werror])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([example.c])

AC_PROG_CC
AM_PROG_CC_C_O
AC_PROG_RANLIB

PKG_CHECK_MODULES([CHECK], [check >= 0.9.5])

AC_HEADER_STDC
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stdlib.h string.h unistd.h])

AC_C_CONST
AC_TYPE_MODE_T
AC_TYPE_OFF_T
AC_TYPE_SIZE_T
AC_TYPE_UINT32_T

AC_FUNC_FORK
AC_FUNC_MALLOC
AC_FUNC_REALLOC
AC_FUNC_STAT
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([memset])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

However I get this weird error:

```
% make check
make  example
gcc -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"example\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"example\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"1.0.0\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"example\ 1.0.0\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"noreply@here.com\" -DPACKAGE=\"example\" -DVERSION=\"1.0.0\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_FORK=1 -DHAVE_VFORK=1 -DHAVE_WORKING_VFORK=1 -DHAVE_WORKING_FORK=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_MALLOC=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_REALLOC=1 -DHAVE_MEMSET=1 -I.    -I/opt/local/include   -std=c99 -g -O2 -MT example-example.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/example-example.Tpo -c -o example-example.o `test -f 'example.c' || echo './'`example.c
example.c: In function 'example':
example.c:3: error: parse error before ',' token
make[1]: *** [example-example.o] Error 1
make: *** [check-am] Error 2
```

So it's finding a syntax error in `fail()` (which I suppose check implements as a macro).  If I remove the `-std=c99` flag, the syntax error goes away, and it works fine.

Is there a way I can fix this?  I definitely want `-std=c99` so that my use (and `check.h`'s use) of variadic macros is ok'd by the compiler.

Comment: Is there any particular reason to use `@@` substitution in the likes of `example_CFLAGS = @CHECK_CFLAGS@ ...`? I always find that `$(CHECK_CFLAGS)` much easier to use in such cases as the user calling `make` can easily override `CHECK_CFLAGS` for debugging build failures and similar things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>The [basic tutorial](http://check.sourceforge.net/doc/check_html/check_3.html#SEC4) on that site always shows the `fail` called between `START_TEST` and `END_TEST` macros. They most likely set some things up for these macros.</strike> Done.

Now all you need to get that to compile is give `fail()` an argument.

It's defined like this:

```
#define fail(...) _fail_unless(0, __FILE__, __LINE__, "Failed" , ## __VA_ARGS__, NULL)
```

Which will have a stray `,` if no argument is given.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Your code does not match the examples. `START_TEST(something) { ... } END_TEST`. You're missing the braces.

Comment: Ah, I missed the sentence that said ["This does not happen if you pass an empty argument, nor does it happen if the token preceding `##' is anything other than a comma."](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html).  THanks!